# What does CPython actually do when "=" is performed on primitive type variables?

Tags: python, cpython, reference-counting

For instance:

```
a = some_process_that_generates_integer_result()
b = a
```

Someone told me that *b* and *a* will point to same chunk of integer object, thus *b* would modify the reference count of that object. The code is executed in function `PyObject* ast2obj_expr(void* _o)` in *Python-ast.c*:

```
static PyObject* ast2obj_object(void *o)
{
    if (!o)
        o = Py_None;
    Py_INCREF((PyObject*)o);
    return (PyObject*)o;
}

......

case Num_kind:
    result = PyType_GenericNew(Num_type, NULL, NULL);
    if (!result) goto failed;
    value = ast2obj_object(o->v.Num.n);
    if (!value) goto failed;
    if (PyObject_SetAttrString(result, "n", value) == -1)
            goto failed;
    Py_DECREF(value);
    break;
```

However, I think modifying reference count without ownership change is really futile. What I expect is that each variable holding primitive values (floats, integers, etc.) always have their own value, instead of referring to a same object.

And in the execution of my simple test code, I found the break point in the above `Num_kind` branch is never reached:

```
def some_function(x, y):
    return (x+y)*（x-y)

a = some_function(666666,66666)
print a

b = a
print a
print b

b = a + 999999
print a
print b

b = a
print a
print b
```

I'm using the python2.7-dbg program provided by Debian. I'm sure the program and the source code matches, because many other break points works properly.

So, what does CPython actually do on primitive type objects?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking here. What break point are you referring to? What kind of behavior were you expecting with that code and how did it not meet your expectations?

Comment: @poke Added missing description. The breakpoint is in the Num_kind branch in above C code, as someone told me that piece of code is relative to run-time numeric varible copying.

Comment: "each variable holding primitive values". Python doesn't actually _have_ variables that hold values. Instead, it has strongly-typed objects that can be bound to names. This is quite different to the C-style data model, and trying to understand the Python data model in C terms is rarely fruitful, unless you happen to be interfacing with C code. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: True, it is common to talk informally about Python variables, but Python names are certainly _not_ like C-like variables, which are named locations in RAM that are declared to hold data of a particular type. A Python name is simply a way of referring to the object; an object may have several names, or none. Note that in Python the type of an object is a quality of the object itself, _not_ of the name(s) it's bound to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, there are no “primitive objects” in Python. Everything is an object, of the same kind, and they are all handled in the same way on the language level. As such, the following assignments work the same way regardless of the values which are assigned:

```
a = some_process_that_generates_integer_result()
b = a
```

In Python, assignments are *always* reference copies. So whatever the function returns, its reference is *copied* into the variable `a`. And then in the second line, the reference is again *copied* into the variable `b`. As such, both variables will refer to the exact same object.

You can easily verify this by using the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function which will tell you the identity of an object:

```
print id(a)
print id(b)
```

This will print the same identifying number twice. Note though, that wil doing just this, you copied the reference two more times: It’s not variables that are *passed* to functions but copies of references.

This is different from other languages where you often differentiate between *“call by value”* and *“call by reference”*. The former means that you create a copy of the value and pass it to a function, which means that new memory is allocated for that value; the latter means that the actual reference is passed and changes to that reference affect the original variable as well.

What Python does is often called *“call by assignment”*: every function call where you pass arguments is essentially an assignment into new variables (which are then available to the function). And an assignment copies the reference.

When everything is an object, this is actually a very simple strategy. And as I said above, what happens with integers is then no different to what happens to other objects. The only “special” thing about integers is that they are *immutable*, so you cannot change their values. This means that an integer object always refers to the *exact same* value. This makes it easy to share the object (in memory) with multiple values. Every operation that yields a new result gives you a different object, so when you do a series of arithmetic operations, you are actually changing what object a variable is pointing to all the time.

The same happens with other immutable objects too, for example strings. Every operation that yields a changed string gives you a different string object.

Assignments with mutable objects however are the same too. It’s just that changing the value of those objects is possible, so they appear different. Consider this example:

```
a = [1] # creates a new list object
b = a # copies the reference to that same list object
c = [2] # creates a new list object
b = a + c # concats the two lists and creates a new list object
d = b
# at this point, we have *three* list objects
d.append(3) # mutates the list object
print(d)
print(b) # same result since b and d reference the same list object
```

---

Now coming back to your question and the C code you cite there, you are actually looking at the wrong part of CPython to get an explanation there. AST is the abstract syntax tree that the parser creates when parsing a file. It reflects the syntax structure of a program but says nothing about the actual run-time behavior yet.

The code you showed for the `Num_kind` is actually responsible for creating `Num` AST objects. You can get an idea of this when using the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
>>> import ast
>>> doc = ast.parse('foo = 5')

# the document contains an assignment
>>> doc.body[0]
<_ast.Assign object at 0x0000000002322278>

# the target of that assignment has the id `foo`
>>> doc.body[0].targets[0].id
'foo'

# and the value of that assignment is the `Num` object that was
# created in that C code, with that `n` property containing the value
>>> doc.body[0].value
<_ast.Num object at 0x00000000023224E0>
>>> doc.body[0].value.n
5
```

If you want to get an idea of the actual evaluation of Python code, you should first look at the byte code. The byte code is what is being executed at run-time by the virtual machine. You can use the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to see byte code for Python code:

```
>>> def test():
        foo = 5

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, there are two major byte code instructions here: `LOAD_CONST` and `STORE_FAST`. `LOAD_CONST` will just load a constant value onto the evaluation stack. In this example, we just load a constant number, but we could also load the value from a function call instead (try playing with the `dis` module to figure out how it works).

The assignment itself is made using `STORE_FAST`. The byte code interpreter does [the following](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L1236) for that instruction:

```c
TARGET(STORE_FAST)
{
    v = POP();
    SETLOCAL(oparg, v);
    FAST_DISPATCH();
}
```

So it essentially gets the value (the reference to the integer object) from the stack, and then calls `SETLOCAL` which essentially will just assign the value to local variable.

Note though, that this does not increase the reference count of that value. That’s what happens with [`LOAD_CONST`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L1227), or any other byte code instruction that gets a value from somewhere:

```c
TARGET(LOAD_CONST)
{
    x = GETITEM(consts, oparg);
    Py_INCREF(x);
    PUSH(x);
    FAST_DISPATCH();
}
```

---

So tl;dr: Assignments in Python are always reference copies. References are also copied whenever a value is used (but in many other situations that copied reference only exists for a short time). The AST is responsible for creating an object representation of parsed programs (only the syntax), while the byte code interpreter runs the previously compiled byte code to do actual stuff at run-time and deal with real objects.