# Why variable assignment behaves differently in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am new to Python and I am quite confused about the following code:

Example 1:

```
n = 1
m = n
n = 2
print(n)   # 2
print(m)   # 1
```

Example 2:

```
names = ["a", "b", "c"]
visitor = names
names.pop()
print(names)      # ['a', 'b']
print(visitor)    # ['a', 'b']
```

Example 1 shows that `n` is 1 and `m` is 1. However, example 2 shows that `names` is ['a', 'b'], and `visitor` is also ['a', 'b'].

To me, example 1 and example 2 are similar, so I wonder why the results are so different? Thank you.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @Pac0: No, that is not how things work. Python has no concept of primitives.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764949/21303427 might help. As @user2357112 said, there are no primitives in Python. Integers are *immutable* objects and Python therefore changes the reference at the assignment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an exact duplicate of this question, I'm just having trouble finding it. In the meantime, these are kinda close: [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](/q/575196/4518341),  [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](/q/2612802/4518341)

Comment: The real difference between your two snippets is in the first one where you have: `n = 2`. It is only the **variable** `n` that you are changing and not what it used to refer to. You are changing it to refer to something else. This affects nothing else, unless you are concerned with reference counting.

Comment: @lord_haffi *"Integers are immutable objects and Python therefore changes the reference at the assignment"* Kind of, but what's relevant is the assignment, not the mutability. Lists are mutable, but in Example 2, doing the assignment `names = names[1:]` (instead of invoking the method `names.pop()`) would leave `visitor` unchanged.

Comment: FAQ: [Why did changing list ‘y’ also change list ‘x’?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x)

Comment: It is important to understand, the *assignment* is working **precisely the same way**

Comment: @Pac0 no, that is not how Python works. `int` objects **have the same exact semantics as any other type of object, inlcuding `list` objects** when you **assign them**

Comment: As Ned says: **"MYTH: Python assigns mutable and immutable values differently."**

Comment: You mean "behave differently *to Java*", you should say that. Python does not have [the concept of a primitive vs a boxed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418296/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-type-is-boxed) as Java does, hence the int assignment does not have aliasing like you expect a Java Integer would. We shouldn't cite the Batchelder essay because it's technically correct but not at all helpful to programmers coming from Java; they just need a very short clear list of the differences.

Comment: **The assignment `m = n` behaves differently in Java depending on whether `m`, `n` are `int`(primitives in Java) or boxed types (`Integer`)**; [due to Java automatically providing auto-boxing and unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251074/why-is-integer-a-10-a-valid-statement-in-java). So the OP's confusion here is *not* just about whether there is aliasing in the list assignment `visitor = names`. So ask the OP to clarify what (Java-like) behavior they expect on the  `m = n` assignment; don't just try to close as being a dupe of aliasing on the list assignment.

Comment: There's a (slightly) newer version of Ned's article: [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Integers* are *not mutable*.  So the only way to change a variable that is assigned to an integer is through assignment.  When you assign `m=n`, `m` is assigned to the same address that `n` currently is assigned. Both `m` and `n` refer to the address of the integer `1`.  `m` will continue to point to `1` even if `n` is assigned to a different value be it an *integer* or something else entirely.

This behavior based on assignment is common to both *mutable* and *immutable* types.

By contrast, `list`s *are mutable* so you can modify by means that are not only assignment.  When you assign `visitor = names`, `visitor` points to the same `list` that `names` is assigned to, just like the above case.  And were you to change the value of `names` through assignment `visitor` would not be impacted. The difference emerges if you mutate the `list`. If you call `names.pop()` for example this mutates the list and `visitor` (and any other variable that was assigned to this `list`) will *see* the mutation.  In your case you mutated the list with a `pop` operation, there are others which we won't go into here.

Comment: "By contrast..." *there is no contrast here*. Assignment works exactly the same in both cases

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The contrast isn't in the assignment, the contrast is the mutability. I spell that out. I've reworded to emphasize the difference

Comment: Being a literal has nothing to do with mutability, and IMO only muddies your point about mutable vs. immutable. I think you should remove the _"literals"_ and just say _"integers (because that's what OP is using) are immutable objects"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that is incorrect, literals are all immutable. So you could say it has everything to do with immutability in this case. I fail to see how it muddied the point. OP is using a numeric literal. OP doesnt say integer anywhere.

Comment: All literals yield objects that are immutable, but all immutables (e.g. `frozenset`s) do not necessarily come from literals. The real answer to OP's question is that assignment is not mutation, so the two snippets aren't equivalent. Mutability is only tangentially relevant in that you couldn't (reasonably) mutate an immutable object, your only option is to create a new one and assign it to the old name.

Comment: perhaps more importantly, *integers are not literals*. A "literal" describes a piece of *source code*, so the discussion about literals is a red-herring

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The fact that you can't mutate integers and you can mutate lists is quite paramount to the explanation of why the two behaviors co-exist. The lack of mutability of numbers is what forces you to change them only by assignment.  Lists are mutable and can be changed by means aside from assignment.  You dont seem to take issue with juanpa.arrivillaga using the term mutable and immutable.

Comment: I never said all immutables come from literals. You're putting words in my mouth. One does not imply the other. You are running down an irrelevant tangent.

Comment: @wjandrea so what is wrong with it now? you're still not answering the question of what is wrong with the  post.  You are proving my point, by continuing to find  tangential things to criticize without being constructive in any shape or form

Comment: @wjandrea The first thing you said to me was literals are not objects.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I wanted to see your reply first to understand your train of thought. The same thing is still wrong, but other aspects of the answer have actually improved since my first comment.

Comment: @UpAndAdam A literal is *one way* of *creating* an int; in other words, it's a *representation* of an object, not the object itself. As the [numeric type docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) say, *"Numbers are created by numeric literals **or** as the result of built-in functions and operators"*, e.g. `int()` -> `0` and `True + True` -> `2`. And, like Pranav said, other immutable objects don't even have a literal representation but still have the same restrictions you're talking about.

Comment: Nothing Pranav said was relevant. Note that I didn't say it was incorrect. I said it wasn't relevant. I have never made any claims about other ways of creating immutable objects. And it's not my obligation to do so. Not sure why you are raising an irrelevant point to me instead of answering the only question that matters: What is wrong with my answer. How does other immutables lacking a literal representation have any relationship to my answer or this post? Other immutables have the same restriction great. What's your point. It doesn't make my answer wrong for not discussing EVERY immutable.

Comment: @UpAndAdam The specific thing that's wrong is you said "Integers are literals". Integers *can be represented by* literals (but that's incidental to the fact that they're immutable, so you don't even need to bring up literals at all in the answer). Everything else we've brought up is just explaining what the terminology actually means.

Comment: I've edited the wording to be less misleading and avoid the category error of equating the syntax to the evaluation result. Note that the use of "literal" here is still rather shaky, as it relies on a specific definition of the formal Python syntax specification; colloquially, many people would also call `["a", "b", "c"]` a literal.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you appreciate the edit.. I thought about it some more and I agree that it will be better to remove mention of literals entirely to avoid opening up a door that doesnt need to be opened.

Comment: I've removed all usage of literals to avoid confusion.  For me it was just natural to think numbers are literals ( because unless they are generated from input or random, they had to come from a literal) and all literals are immutable. it would have been far more constructive and efficient if instead of all the tangential issues raised (several of which explaining to me things I already knew), the focused response was "it would be best to avoid mentioning literals entirely because its an unnneeded complication" rather than arguing / explaining pedantic semantics.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the fundamental difference. In the first case, with integers:

```
n = 2
```

Does *not* mutate whatever `n` was. This is because assignment is not a mutation. However, in the second case:

```
names.pop()
```

you are calling the method `.pop` which is a *mutator method*.

That's it. Note, you can get the exact same behavior of the first case using lists:

```
>>> n = []
>>> m = n
>>> n = ['hi']
>>> print(n)
['hi']
>>> print(m)
[]
```

Because assignment did not mutate anything.

Note, `int` objects *expose no mutator methods*, i.e. they are "immutable". Of course, that isn't *magic*.

We can use implementation details to reach into the internals of an `int` and actually mutate it.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> my_integer = 1337
>>> pointer = ctypes.cast(id(my_integer), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
>>> pointer[6] = 99
>>> my_integer
99
```

Ok, now, let's re-create your original example, this time using this approach to *mutate the immutable int*:

```
>>> n = 1337 # not messing with lower valued ints because they are cached
>>> m = n
>>> ctypes.cast(id(n), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))[6] = 999
>>> print(n)
999
>>> print(m)
999
```

Note, the above was written with Python 3.11 in mind. Later versions may change the layout of `int` objects, so `pointer[6] = whatever` isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: "Because assignment did not mutate anything." This may be misleading; only assignment to function-local names does not mutate anything. Non-name assignments like `a.b = c` do usually mutate, and in class namespaces even bare name assignments can trigger mutation.

Answer (score -1):

In you first example `m` and `n` are two different objects. You can see that by comparing their object ids.

```py
id(m) == id(n) # False
```

In the second example `visitor` is not a new list object, because the variable `names` only contains a reference to a list object. You only copied this reference, but not the list itself. Both variables store a reference to the same object.

```py
id(names) == id(visitor) # True
```

You can get a shallow copy of the list by calling its `copy()` method.

```py
names = ["a", "b", "c"]
visitor = names.copy()
names.pop()
print(names)              # ['a', 'b']
print(visitor)            # ['a', 'b', 'c']
id(names) == id(visitor)  # False
```

Comment: in the first example, `m` and `n` are the same objet after you do `m = n`

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this explanation is. Obviously `m` and `n` are different objects because their **values** are different; you don't need to check their IDs to see that. Secondly, "`visitor` is not a new list object" in exactly the same way that `m` is not a new **int** object, and "`names` only contains a reference to a list object" in exactly the same way that `n` only contains a reference to an **int** object. [Juanpa's answer](/a/77153502/4518341) covers the actual fundamental difference: rebinding vs mutating.